# jquery not fully working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

this is the link http://carboncreditcapital.com/calculator/

I don't understand why the page returns the json when the page loads.
It suppose to autocomplete when user types in the input field to return related airport names

I don't know which files i should edit to make jquery work properly in wordpress

```
<?php

?>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<div>
    From
    <div class="textinput">
        <input type="text" id="dept" name="departure" placeholder="City name or aiport code" style="width: 120px">
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    To
<div>
<input type="text" id="dest" placeholder="City name or airport code" style="width: 120px">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#dept').autocomplete({
        source:'source.php',
        minLength:1,

    }); 


    jQuery('#dest').autocomplete({
        source:'source.php',
        minLength:1,

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you need to use a different version of jquery function
to kickstart the DOC load option

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#dept').autocomplete({
         source:'source.php',
         minLength:1
     }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you know why all json data are automatically displaying on the page when the page loads. The data should be returned after the trigger.

Comment: Please give us the code for the trigger to answer that question, user3371790

Comment: The autocomplete jquery should be the trigger.